# What does y.ravel().shape[0] do?

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused about the below mentioned code:

```
if y.ravel().shape[0] > 1:
```

When y.ravel() always returns a 1D-Array and shape[0] returns the number of the rows, so

```
y.ravel().shape[0]
```

would always return 1, would'nt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one dimensional array's shape is a 1-tuple. The first (and only) value is the array's length. There is no distinction between rows and columns when you're dealing with a one dimensional array, those concepts presume two dimensions. After calling `ravel()`, you don't have those dimensions, even if the original array did.

The `if` statement's condition will be true if the array contains more than one element. It doesn't care where those elements are, or what the original shape of the array was.

So any of these arrays would be valid:

```
a = np.array([1,2])       # one dimensional, shape=(2,)
b = np.array([[1, 2]])    # two dimensional, shape=(1, 2)
c = np.array([[1], [2]])  # two dimensional, shape=(2, 1)
```

None of these would be:

```
d = np.array([])                    # empty
e = np.array([1])                   # only one value
f = np.array([[[1]]])               # the number of dimensions doesn't matter
g = np.array([[[], []], [[], []]])  # empty with more dimensions
```

Answer (score 0):

No, maybe this is used to check if `y` is empty.

e.g.

```
y = np.array([])
y.ravel().shapep[0]
```

result is `0`

Comment: Ok, but the condition would never be true? So the if-condition is nonsense?